# SystemError: <built-in function xxx_iterator> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to upgrade from:
SWIG 2.0.11 and Python 2.7.12 to
SWIG 3.0.12 and Python 3.6,
but I get the following exception when I run the tests on any iterator (automatically generated using %template):

```
SystemError: <built-in function xxx_iterator> returned a result with an error set
```

For example, even the simplest iteration fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testRender.py", line 459, in testRender
    for v in vertices:
File "ncore.py", line 90833, in __iter__
    return self.iterator()
File "ncore.py", line 90830, in iterator
    return _ncore.Vertices_iterator(self)
SystemError: <built-in function Vertices_iterator> returned a result with an error set
```

Any ideas?

Again, this was all working great with SWIG 2.0.11 and Python 2.7.12....

**Edit: Adding simpler example:**

It could be ANY %template-generated iterator, so, for example, this template, defined in the .i file:

```
%template(Ints) std::list<int>;
```

will fail when using this simple code:

```
intsList = ncore.Ints()
intsList.append(1)
intsList.append(2)
for i in intsList:
    print(i)
```

with a message similar to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testRender.py", line 459, in testRender
    for i in intsList:
File "ncore.py", line 90833, in __iter__
    return self.iterator()
File "ncore.py", line 90830, in iterator
    return _ncore.Ints_iterator(self)
SystemError: <built-in function Ints_iterator> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: without knowing the source code for `Vertices_iterator` it's impossible to give any help.

Comment: FYI, it looks like this commit (https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/560/files) attempted to fix a similar issue...

Comment: If you want me to be able to look at this you need a real minimal complete example that I can get running in my own debugger. I ignored it before because there isn't one and even with a bounty I still can't help. The traceback shows at least 459 lines of Python you've not shown​ in your "simple test case" that could be related and goodness knows how much else in the rest of ncore C and Python generated code. If you really want an answer you need to isolate it to something we can reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

That is strange, just recompiled everything from scratch. Then I tested your simplified example (if understood correctly):

Mytest.i:

```
%module mytest                                                                                             
%{                                                                                                       
    #include <list>
     using namespace std;                                                                                     
%}                                                                                                       

%include "std_list.i"
namespace std {                                                                                          
    %template(Ints) list<int>;                                                           
}
```

Compile steps:

```
swig -Wall -c++ -python -py3 -o mytest_wrap.cpp mytest.i
g++ -c -g -ansi mytest_wrap.cpp -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m/ -fPIC -o mytest_wrap.o
g++ -g -ansi -o _mytest.so mytest_wrap.o -shared
```

Then, after importing mytest module to python, everything works like a charm.

Tested configurations:

- dockerized Ubuntu16.04: Python 3.6.1, SWIG 3.0.12, g++ 5.4.
- dockerized Centos6: Python 3.6.1, SWIG 3.0.12, g++ (4.9.2 and 4.4.7)

Comment: Thanks for testing. I should mention we tried with g++ 4.6 and g++ 4.9 on Centos 6, and MSVS Pro 2013 on Windows.

Comment: @DevanWilliams Works for me also on Centos6/g++ 4.6. Does this simple proposed example produce exactly the same problem? Is there any compilation warning?

Answer (score -1):

Though it's an old question relatively, but recently I encountered a similar issue (`<built-in function delete_qpol_iterator_t> returned a result with an error set`) while dealing with SELinux and setools in CentOS7 docker. Building and installing libsepol and libselinux from [source code](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux) might solve the problem.

So I guess updating relevant libs and other dependencies might be useful.